# how to find the file is created or updated current date/day

Tags: perl

how to find the file is created or updated current date/day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `-M` function to see if the file has been modified in the last day:

```
if(-M FH < 1) {
    # file was modified less than one day ago
}
```

You can also test for time since the inode was changed with `-C`, which is often (but not always) when the file was created (see [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#Files-and-Filesystems) for filesystem compatibility issues).

See [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) for some examples of the various filetests.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want day and date of the file when it was last modified, you can try like this

```
use strict;
use warning;
use File::stat;
use Time::localtime;

my $st = stat($file) or die "No $file: $!";
my $datetime_string = ctime($st->mtime);

print "file $file was updated at $datetime_string\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Show on File::Stat. You can use DateTime to init the timestamp with local time zone.